# Is it possible to create deeplink that survives iOS app installs Without using third party solution?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Is it possible to create deep link that

1> Redirect user From App A to specific content of the another app B if the app is installed ?

2> If App B is not installed , redirect user to web page from where user can go and install App B

When App B is opened up after installation user should see that specific content.

Here App A and App B Are from different developer but have common SDK integrated which uses same backend

I do not want to use third party solution like branch or Firebase dynamic link.

Comment: Have you found any potential solution/leads on this? I'm looking at how firebase dynamic links achieves this.